# react load image with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image

I am working on a new react object with react

i am using redux and it works fine on the route I am setting the state

> but when I navigate to another route using **link tag** I get the
> state from store and use it to display some content and the text
> appears perfectly but in the template the image I get not loaded

I inspected the page and copy the src attr from html and paste it to a new tab  it's work fine

```
 <img src={`127.0.0.1:8000${profileInfo.cover_image}`}id="cover-photo" />
```

> here what I mean [the inspect url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Jjv.png)
>
> the link in src attr [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4motx.png)

I dont know why the image not loaded in the template seems every think fine

thanks for help

Comment: did you try using require() inside img tag

Comment: @omar yes I did it throw an error in console `module not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an invalid URL.

You should use:

```js
`//127.0.0.1:8000${profileInfo.cover_image}`
or
`http://127.0.0.1:8000${profileInfo.cover_image}`
```

It works when you paste it in a new tab, because the browser is trying to guess the correct protocol from user input, but it doesn't do the same inside pages because that's supposed to be a correct reference.

Comment: Thanks man, I put it like this in one component and forgot in another :), appreciate it.